# Woocommerce custom payment gateway workflow using redirection

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway

I am new to WooCommerce custom payment gateway(PG) integrations.

Initial Page: The checkout page of WooCommerce. I have created a custom plugin based on instructions from here:
http://www.sitepoint.com/building-a-woocommerce-payment-extension/
and 
http://docs.woothemes.com/document/payment-gateway-api/

So, when I visit the checkout page, I can see my payment gateway at the bottom. My Code:

**Constructor**:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->id                   = 'xxxx_payment_gateway';
    $this->title                = __( "xxxx Payment Gateway", 'woocommerce-xxxx-gateway' );
    $this->icon                 = null;
    $this->method_title         = __( 'xxxx Payment Gateway', 'woocommerce-xxxx-gateway' );
    $this->method_description   = __( 'Take payments via xxxx Payment Gateway - uses the xxxx Payment Gateway SDK.', 'woocommerce-xxxx-gateway' );
    $this->has_fields           = true;

    $this->init_form_fields();
    $this->init_settings();

    // Save settings
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways_' . $this->id, array( &$this, 'process_admin_options' ) );
    }
}
```

**process_payment**

```
function process_payment( $order_id ) {
    $customer_order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    $country_list = array(
        "IN"=>"IND",
    );
    $environment_url = 'http://example.com/pgic/pgserv.php';
    $payload = array(
        "x_invoice_num"         => str_replace( "#", "", $customer_order->get_order_number() ),
        "x_merchant_id"         => $this->merchant_id, 
        // Order total
        "x_amount"              => 3,//$customer_order->order_total,
        // Billing Information
        "x_first_name"          => $customer_order->billing_first_name,
        ....
        // Shipping Information
        "x_ship_to_first_name"  => $customer_order->shipping_first_name,
        ....
        "x_cust_id"             => $customer_order->user_id,
        "x_customer_ip"         => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],
    );
    $response = wp_remote_post( $environment_url, 
        array(
            'method'    => 'POST',
            'body'      => http_build_query( $payload ),
            'timeout'   => 90,
            'sslverify' => false,
        ) 
    );
    $forwardURL = trim(wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ));

    if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) 
    {
        // Return failure redirect
        return array(
            'result'    => 'failure',
            'redirect'  => 'failed.php'
        );
    }
    else{
        // Reduce stock levels
        // $order->reduce_order_stock();

        // Remove cart
        // WC()->cart->empty_cart();

        // Return thankyou redirect
        return array(
            'result'    => 'success',
            'redirect'  => $forwardURL //$this->get_return_url( $customer_order )
        );
    }
}//process_payment
```

My PG vendor gave me a following process to integrate.

Page 1: The above plugin process_payment passes on to the payment gateway processing to the pgserv.php.

Page 2: Automatically my bank's page comes up (because of the credit card of my bank that I use) where I provide my OTP and all.

Page 3: Once that step is complete, the payment gateway forwards from there to another success landing page (let's call it **pgresponse.php**)  within my website that returns the transaction result.

This is where the problem begins. 
I tried redirecting/submitting to an independent page (submitaction.php) where I try to mark the order complete/payment complete and empty the cart. My Code:

```
global $woocommerce, $post;
$order = new WC_Order($post->ID);
$payment_status = $order->payment_complete();
```

No matter what I do, the order in this case doesn't update status to payment complete. Even **$payment_status** doesn't return anything.

Questions:

1. What do I do?
2. I intend to write a hook for process_order_status to send mails. The way I am planning would be to write the following code in the plugin:

   ```
   public function process_order_status( $order, $payment_id, $status, $auth_code ) {
       echo "Payment details :: $order, $payment_id, $status, $auth_code";
       error_log("Payment details :: $order, $payment_id, $status, $auth_code");
       if ( 'APPROVED' == $status ) {
           // Payment complete
           $order->payment_complete( $payment_id );
           // Add order note
           $order->add_order_note( sprintf( __( 'Payment approved (ID: %s, Auth Code: %s)', 'woocommerce' ), $payment_id, $auth_code ) );
           // Remove cart
           WC()->cart->empty_cart();
           return true;
       }
       return false;
   }//process_order_status
   ```

Would that be correct? If only I could get the order to update the payment status, I am sure this method would be called, correct?

I am desperate for some help. Any link or just direction would also be fine. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decode payload being sent to the payment provider. Do something like this.

```
public function check_ipn_response($payload)
{
    $raw_input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),TRUE);
    $order_id = $raw_input['callback_data'];
    // get order_id
    $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
    // Update order status once order is complete
    $order->update_status( 'processing', _x( 'Payment Complete', 'Check payment method', 'wc-gateway-paymentsgy' ) );
    wp_die();
}
```